# JQuery dropdownlist/select onchange event not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have this dropodownlist / combobox / select element inside an asp.net form:

```
<asp:DropDownList 
 ID="_ddlMode" 
 runat="server" 
 AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
 ClientIDMode="Static" 
 CssClass="input_medium" 
 DataSourceID="_sdsModes" 
 DataTextField="description" 
 DataValueField="id">
 <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="None" Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I need to call function `SetModes()` when the selected element is changed from the user.
I tried with this:

```
 $(function () {
   $(document.body).on('change', '_ddlMode', function () {
       var _index = $("select[id='_ddlMode'] option:selected").index();
       SetModes(_txtBank, _txtZip, _index);
   });
 });
```

No luck. Then I tried this:

```
 $(function () {
    _ddlMode= $("input[id$='_ddlMode']");

    _ddlMode.change(
        function () {
           var _index = $("select[id='_ddlMode'] option:selected").index();
           SetModes(_txtBank, _txtZip, _index);
        }
    );
});
```

Again no luck.... where's the error?
There's a more efficent way to retrieve the index of the selected element within the event handling ?

P.S. I'm using `jquery-.2.1.3`, `jquery-ui-1.11.2`

Comment: `$(document.body).on('change', '_ddlMode',` -> `$(document.body).on('change', '#_ddlMode',` or `$(document.body).on('change', "select[id='_ddlMode']",` as you have this on the next line and implies you might be using the same ID multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are willing to hit a method in your `javascript` code and it is not working for you. There could be many reasons behind why it is not hitting it, I would write few of those possible reasons here with their respective possible solution.

**Reason:** 
Since you are using jQuery to bind the dropdownlist with a change event, I would suspect if your jQuery is being referenced correctly.

**Solution:** 
Go to the browser's dev tools' `console` tab (`CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `I`) and see if you have any error with jQuery not being loaded, If yes then fix it.

---

**Reason:** 
As @freedomn-m has pointed out in the comments, You are not specifying a css selector, in your case `#` before your `id` while binding the event.

**Solution:**

```
$(function () {
   $(document.body).on('change', '#_ddlMode', function () {
       var _index = $("select[id='_ddlMode'] option:selected").index();
       SetModes(_txtBank, _txtZip, _index);
   });
 });
```

---

**Reason:** 
Your event is not getting bound to the desired control. This could be very specific to `ASP.NET` Web Forms, as you can face it while you are building your web apps.

So, technically, `ASP.NET` can modify the IDs of your controls when you compile them and it could be a possible reason for not hitting the method.

For example, if you have a `ContentPlaceHolder` with an `id` of `cph_1` and have markup in it as your child page, then `ASP.NET` will concatenate that id with every nested server control of yours. So, if you have a `textbox` with an `id` of `tb1` in that content place holder, it would get modified to `cph1_tb1` when browsing through that page.

**Solution:** 
Bind your event with the help of this syntax (`<%%>`) like below:

```
$(function () {
   $(document.body).on('change', '#<%= _ddlMode.ClientID %>', function () {
       var _index = $("select[id='<%= _ddlMode.ClientID %>'] option:selected").index();
       SetModes(_txtBank, _txtZip, _index);
   });
 });
```

See, if you can resolve the issue with these solutions.

Comment: # was the key! :-)